# jQuery autocomplete (devbridge) search from beginning

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using devbridge's autocomplete jQuery script.
Is there an option to filter the search from the beginning of the word and not to apply to anywhere in a word?

Like if I would type "R" then I would like to see only the words starting with R and not the R character in every word.

Basicly a search from beginning kind of filter is what I am looking for.

How could this be done? Is there an option for this?

```
<script>
$(function() {

var fruits = [
   { value: 'Apple',  data: 'Apple' },
   { value: 'Pear',   data: 'Pear' },
   { value: 'Carrot', data: 'Carrot' },
   { value: 'Cherry', data: 'Cherry' },
   { value: 'Banana', data: 'Banana' },
   { value: 'Radish', data: 'Radish' }
];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        lookup: fruits,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        },
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: "search from the beginning of the *world*"... you want to search all 4.5 billion years? :)

Comment: Sorry... I hate my keyboard... It always does that.. :D

Comment: Thanks for editing the fun out of your question :) Please also show any code/HTML you have attempted (before you start getting down-votes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add lookupFilter function:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    lookup: fruits,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
        return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
    }
});
```