# jQuery autocomplete (devbridge) lookupFilter to search multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, autocomplete

I have below code-

```
$(function() {

var fruits = [
   { value: 'Apple',id: '123',  data: 'Apple' },
   { value: 'Pear', id: '543',   data: 'Pear' },
   { value: 'Carrot', id: '123', data: 'Carrot' },
   { value: 'Cherry', id: '234', data: 'Cherry' },
   { value: 'Banana', id: '543', data: 'Banana' },
   { value: 'Radish', id: '3423', data: 'Radish' }
];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        lookup: fruits,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        },
  });
});
```

I want to do search based on 'value' and 'id' both. There is lookupFilter function but i dont know how to use it. Here is original script - https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/
and Here is something similer question - [jQuery autocomplete (devbridge) search from beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313580/jquery-autocomplete-devbridge-search-from-beginning)

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with below code:

```
$(function() {

var fruits = [
   { value: 'Apple',id: '123',  data: 'Apple' },
   { value: 'Pear', id: '543',   data: 'Pear' },
   { value: 'Carrot', id: '123', data: 'Carrot' },
   { value: 'Cherry', id: '234', data: 'Cherry' },
   { value: 'Banana', id: '543', data: 'Banana' },
   { value: 'Radish', id: '3423', data: 'Radish' }
];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        lookup: fruits,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        },
        lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
            return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) < -1 || suggestion.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) < -1; //checking with both id as well as value
        }
  });
});
```

Note: I couldn't able to test this code but i believe it should work for you.

Comment: are you sure you did it like `suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) < -1`. If yes; then i will update the answer so that other people can refer it

Comment: I'm not sure that is right. I changed to "=== 0" instead of "< -1" and then it worked for me. Like the answer from Yosvel.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with the previous answers I'd like to correct.

- [Yosvel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932552/yosvel-quintero-arguelles)'s solution only returns Strings starting exaclty with the query. Meaning, searching for "App" returns "Apple", but searching for "ple", doesn't return "Apple", which should be the default behaviour of `devbridge-autocomplete` we want to keep *(if not desired otherwise)*.
- [vijayP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321167/vijayp)'s answer doesn't return, what we are searching. The `less-than`-oprator `<` has to be turned around to a `greater-than`-operator `>`, because wa want to return items where `.indexOf(query)` returned a value greater than -1, meaning the query has been found somewehere in either `id`, or `value`.

Thank you for helping me! Here's the correct solution:

```
var fruits = [
   { value: 'Apple',id: '123',  data: 'Apple' },
   { value: 'Pear', id: '543',   data: 'Pear' },
   { value: 'Carrot', id: '123', data: 'Carrot' },
   { value: 'Cherry', id: '234', data: 'Cherry' },
   { value: 'Banana', id: '543', data: 'Banana' },
   { value: 'Radish', id: '3423', data: 'Radish' }
];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        lookup: fruits,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        },
        lookupFilter(suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
            return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) > -1 || suggestion.id.indexOf(query) > -1; //checking with both id as well as value
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

lookupFilter: `function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {}` filter function for local lookups. By default it does partial string match (case insensitive).

Code:

```js
var fruits = [{value: 'Apple',id: '123',data: 'Apple'}, {value: 'Pear',id: '543',data: 'Pear'}, {value: 'Carrot',id: '123',data: 'Carrot'}, {value: 'Cherry',id: '234',data: 'Cherry'}, {value: 'Banana',id: '543',data: 'Banana'}, {value: 'Radish',id: '3423',data: 'Radish'}];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: fruits,
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    lookupFilter: function(suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
        var id = suggestion.id,
            value = suggestion.value.toLowerCase();
        return id.indexOf(query) === 0 || value.indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.26/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="fruit" id="autocomplete"/>
```